# Autosize div to fit fluid content

Tags: css

I am designing a fluid page which requires:

parent: 80% (of the screen)
container contains x number of images, width:10%, float left.
The container needs to be autosized as wide as the content,  max-width is 50% of the parent.

I have tried different techniques to set display to inline-block, and attached the jsfiddle here.  http://jsfiddle.net/7D9XS/

```
#parent
{
    width: 80%;
}

#container {
    max-width:50%;
    border:solid 1px red;
    display:inline-block;
}

.uploadItemPreviewThumbDiv
{

    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: cyan;
    float:left;
}


.uploadItemPreviewThumbDiv img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: 50% or auto sized, pick one.

Comment: Don't quite understand, does that mean we can't achieve it without Javascript ?

Comment: That means it’s not clear what you want. 50% are 50%, so where does “auto size” come into play, what do you mean by that in this context?

Comment: got it now, I will fix the question.

Comment: Dude! You are using float, and bros dont let bros use float when you want the container element to have a specific width(without specifying one).

Comment: @Itay, you linked to the same fiddle as op.

Comment: @wardha-Web I don't want the #container to have a specific width, I just want it to fit whatever it contains (if we use inline-block), when content has fluid width

Answer (score 0):

OK, Here you go...

```
.uploadItemPreviewThumbDiv
{
    width: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: cyan;
    float:left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/7D9XS/7/)

Remember, the problem here was that the whole of the talk was going on in percentages.. and percentages tend to be one of the most unreliable things that you can come across while developing responsive designs, and on a side note, if I were you i'd use jquery plugins like Isotope or http://mixitup.io/

And Yeah, this is as far as i know, maybe someone could explain quiet better clearer..

Comment: sorry pal, like I said, content is of fluid width, so setting it to 70px does not meet the requirements. Yeah, I am just trying to avoid JS if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Let me try to put it this way...

This is sort of a **paradox**, where your conditions are..

1. You want your innerelements(content) to be of a certain percentage
   width of the container.
2. But on the same time you dont want to specify what the width of the container would exactly be.
3. Because you want the container to be "autosized as wide as the content"
4. Which again brings us back to the 1st point.

It is like both the 'container' and the 'innerelements' are arguing over who should take the responsibility of being a specific width ***First***, and each one is telling the other to attain a specific width, so that he himself can then adjust his own width based on that.

Comment: Well, let's break it down from my perspective:
1. I have a container, which is 50% size of the screen/body.
2. I want to have n pictures (say 3), they have to be say 15%, i.e. 15% of the 50% width.
3. I want to draw a border around these pictures.

Does this help you to understand the problem better?